# Something happened when I created and added values to my struct thats resulting in a segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I made some updates to my RPC program and now its segfaulting, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The difference between the two is the removal of the if statements that assign values to the `args` struct.

Segfaults

```
void
database_1(char *host, char *action, char *message)
{        
    printf("Action: %s\n", action);
    printf("Message: %s\n", message);
    CLIENT *clnt;
    rpc_args  *result_1;
    //struct rpc_args  action_1_arg;

    //rpc arguments struct to pass to server
    struct rpc_args *args = malloc(sizeof(struct rpc_args));

    char *id = generate_id();  
    if (strcmp(action, "GET") == 0) {
        strcpy(args->action, action);
        strcpy(args->id, id);
    } else if(strcmp(action, "PUT") == 0) {
        strcpy(args->action, action);
        strcpy(args->id, id);
        strcpy(args->message.content, message);
    }

#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, DATABASE, ASSIGNMENT_7, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif  /* DEBUG */

    result_1 = action_1(args, clnt);
    if (result_1 == (rpc_args *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
#ifndef DEBUG
    free(args);
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}
```

Doesn't SegFault

```
void
database_1(char *host, char *action, char *message)
{        
    printf("Action: %s\n", action);
    printf("Message: %s\n", message);
    CLIENT *clnt;
    rpc_args  *result_1;
    //struct rpc_args  action_1_arg;

    //rpc arguments struct to pass to server
    struct rpc_args *args = malloc(sizeof(struct rpc_args));

    char *id = generate_id();  

#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, DATABASE, ASSIGNMENT_7, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif  /* DEBUG */

    result_1 = action_1(args, clnt);
    if (result_1 == (rpc_args *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
#ifndef DEBUG
    free(args);
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}
```

Comment: Can you show `struct rpc_args`?. Members `action` and `id` are probably char pointers? If so, you must allocate memory for each of them also.

Comment: @user1320881 yes this is exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us the definition of the `struct`, but make sure it looks something like this:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 128

struct rpc_args {
    /* other members here */
    char action[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char id[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
};
```

Similarly, the `struct` used at `args->message.content` must also be defined this way.

If you use something like the above implementation, make sure you check the length of the strings you are copying to be less than `MAX_STRING_SIZE - 1`.

Alternatively, before using `strcpy` into those members, you can dynamically allocate space for the strings with `malloc`, then `free` them when you clean up the structure.